# Looking for correct data type marker in BCP.FMT for T-SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a bcp.fmt file for a bulk insert in T-SQL (more transportable and user-readable than SSIS), but don't know the SQLCHAR equivalent for a DATETIME column in my destination table (bizarrely, I can't even get an answer from Google). As a consequence, I'm getting this error:

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (ModifyDate).

It's not an unreasonable error msg - I just need to find the equivalent target data type reference, right?

Extract from FMT file below:

4   SQLCHAR   0   8   ";"   4   ModifyDate   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: It is probably an issue with datetime format in the file being dd/mm/yyyy while sql server may be expecting in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Where is your source data coming from?

Comment: This was just a CSV file. In the end I ditched the format file:
BULK INSERT dbo.StockLevelTMP
FROM 'c:\DataFile.csv'
WITH
 (
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
 FIRSTROW = 2
 )

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLCHAR but set the correct dateformat for the input. e.g. `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;`

[SET DATEFORMAT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

Or if you control the input file then use an ISO 8601 format for unambiguous input.